python polars in jupyter lab leads to error due to infer_schema_legth
I often run into data fetching errors when I'm working in JupyterLab and trying to use polars instead of pandas as the dataframe library.
I do this by running the statement
%config SqlMagic.autopolars = True

However, when I try to fetch some data with the %%sql magic command, I often get an error like this one:
ComputeError: could not append value: "Dr." of type: str to the builder;
make sure that all rows have the same schema or consider increasing `infer_schema_length`
it might also be that a value overflows the data-type's capacity

I know that polars default length for schema inference is 100 and normally I would just increase it in the following way:
df = pl.read_database(query=qry, connection=con, infer_schema_length=10_000)

I'd like to set the option globally, so that I can continue to profit from the convenience of jupyters magic commands, but I didn't find an obvious way to do so, using the polars.Config object.
Help would be much appreciated
